# Tableau to Athena error when trying to read tables created with datatypes using python pyspark.sql.types lib

Tags: python, pyspark, tableau-api, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Currently using a glue job written in python to change data types of selected columns. After processing Tableau is unable to open my file and receive the following error message: An error occurred while loading the data.
[Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split

Athena is however able to open and read my files without any issues

```
import logging
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
#from urlparse import urlparse
from datetime import date, timedelta
import boto3
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date,date_format,to_timestamp

def change_datatypes_swg(initialDF, parquet_datatype):

    # assume no transforms

    integer_columns = []
    bigint_columns = []
    decimal_columns = []
    timestamp_columns = []
    print ('test')

    # create transformation map
    transform_map = {
        "table_name": {
            "integer_columns": ["col1"],
            "bigint_columns": ["col2","col3"],
            "decimal_columns": ["col4"],
            "timestamp_columns":  [("timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")],
        }
    }
    print ('test2')
    # populate transforms if needed
   

    if log_type in transform_map:
        parquet_path = parquet_path.replace("/parquet", "/parquet_datatype/")
        integer_columns = transform_map[log_type]["integer_columns"]
        bigint_columns = transform_map[log_type]["bigint_columns"]
        decimal_columns = transform_map[log_type]["decimal_columns"]
        timestamp_columns = transform_map[log_type]["timestamp_columns"]

    formattedDF = initialDF

    # convert to integers
    for integer_column in integer_columns:
        formattedDF = formattedDF.astype(integer_column, col(integer_column).cast(IntegerType()))
        print ('integer_column', formattedDF )

    for bigint_column in bigint_columns:
        formattedDF = formattedDF.withColumn(bigint_column, col(bigint_column).cast(LongType()))
        print ('bigint_column', formattedDF)
    
    for decimal_column in decimal_columns:
        formattedDF = formattedDF.withColumn(decimal_column, col(decimal_column).cast(DecimalType()))
        print ('decimal_column', formattedDF)

    # convert to timestamp
    for timestamp_column in timestamp_columns:
        column_name, column_format = timestamp_column
        formattedDF = formattedDF.withColumn(column_name, to_timestamp(col(column_name), column_format))
        print ('timestamp_column', formattedDF)
    print('FormattedDFS', formattedDF)
    return (formattedDF, parquet_datatype)
```

I was wondering if anyone has come across an issue like this. I don't understand how the files are able to be read using Athena and Redshift but not Tableau to Athena. I was wondering if anyone has any alternatives to using pyspark.sql.types. Is there another lib that can work?